# How to fetch fragments of FragmentStatePagerAdapter of ViewPager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

*If there is any ambiguity in my question then please comment.The problem is really worse and I cannot present it better than this.*

I have this design format in my application -

Activity->Fragment->ViewPager(Nested Fragments).

In Fragment's onCreateMethod I load a long list using AsyncTask.In the onPostExecute() of AsyncTask I assign the adapter to viewPager.

1st point -> I create listfragments of pager in this way-I divide the total list into small listFragments of 10 items each.

To survive Screen Orientation,I used setRetainInstance(true) in the onCreate() of Fragment.Rules say that parent fragment also retains child fragments.When first time activity is loaded,getItem() of FragmentStatePagerAdapter is called twice because it creates two fragments in the run(1st page and second page).

Now when I rotate the screen,due to setRetainInstance(true),onCreate() of parent fragment is not called.Hence the list is not loaded again and previously loaded list is intact.However my screen becomes completely empty(app does not crash).

getItem() of FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not called even once because ChildfragmentManager stores the instances of fragments already created(Am I right?).In onActivityCreated() of parent fragment I again assign the adapter to viewPager.

My Question is why my screen is empty and why does not getItem gets called?If it does not get called then how can I retreive the already created fragments of viewPager.

Second Question is pretty weird - After rotating the screen indicators are still showing but when I swipe from 2nd to 3rd page then app crashes probably because childFragmentManager did not store that page.However getItem() is called in this case.How to deal with this?

Relevant Code is - >

Activity - Inside onCreateMethod

```
if(savedInstanceState==null){

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("NAME", NAME);
        bundle.putInt("VALUE", VALUE);
        bundle.putString("CATEGORY_ID", CATEGORY_ID);
        QuestionFragment fragobj = new QuestionFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.questions, fragobj);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

ParentFragment -> Inside onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    AsyncTask.execute();}
```

Inside onActivityCreated()->

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) getView().findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);}
```

FragmentStatePagerAdapter() ->

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("Akshat","QuestionFragment - Inside getCount Method MyAdapter");
        return NUM_ITEMS;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        Log.v("Akshat","QuestionFragment - Inside getItem Method MyAdapter");
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(pos);
    }
}
```

ArrayListFragment - I am forming these using the list which I have downloaded from external server and dividing these lists into several small lists of 10 items each.

It's really urgent.I cannot figure at all.How to handle screen rotation for fragments of viewPagers?

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem . I am facing the same issue